# Vue router, redirect when the url isnt a match to the correct url

Tags: vue.js

Probaly a simple solution but I cant seem to find it. I have a couple of routes and a redirect. The redirect should prevent to use of a wrong language prefix(slug or how its called) and redirect it to the correct set value. I dont want to use a long list of values that I cant use but use a wildcard for it

```
    {
        path: `/:locale(de|nl|es|it|...and many more)?`,
        redirect: `/en`
    },
    // the idea
    {    
        path: `/:locale(!en)?`,//not working
        redirect: `/en`
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{    
  path: `/:locale/:slug`,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    var slug = to.path.split("/");
    //to get last value on route
    let lang = slug[slug.length - 1];
    if(lang !== "en"){
      next({ path: '/en'})
    }
  
},
```

Comment: Shouldn't `slug ` be accessible in params?

Comment: you can access `slug` in params. @EstusFlask

Comment: Sorry I did see that my code wasnt correct, it now is therfore youre code isnt going to work

Comment: Please expand your answer to provide an explanation as to why this solution works.